# Sending body in HttpClient delete method (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm migrating Http to HttpClient in an Angular 5 application and everything went fine until I got to this method of one of the services:

```
deleteMultipleObjects(userId: number, officeId : number, objectsData : any) {
  const url = `${APP_URL}/delete-objects/${userId}/${officeId}`;

  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  this.appOptionsService.log("Deleting multiple objects.....", url, objectsData);

  return this.http
    .delete(url, { headers : headers, body : objectsData } )
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

As you can see, I pass an object `objectsData` in the body of the delete call that basically has this structure:

```
{
  objectIds: [id1, id2, id3, ...]
}
```

I see that the `delete` method in the `HttpClient` doesn't allow to include a body, so how could I send the array of object ids to delete with the call? I have a lot of delete calls that are the same as this one, so I'll have to change a lot of things in the code to adapt it...

Thanks!

Comment: The body for delete method is not preferable so many platforms have started to ignore the body for delete request.

Comment: So, if I want to delete several objects at once, do I have to use a PUT request instead of a DELETE?

Comment: Yes. That's the only workaround to achieve multiple delete.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change all the calls then... cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send body in `DELETE` http request in Angular.

HTTP specification on MDN says that this possible.  [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE).

If you need this functionality, you should use `PUT` as workaround. Another method to allow multiple e.g. id's on your delete API endpoint. For example:

```
https://server.com/api/delete?ids=1,2,3,4,5
```

That requires some changes on your api.

Comment: I changed the DELETE requests for PUT equivalents, so I can use the body in the call to send the objects to be deleted.

Comment: the HTTP Delete MAY have a body. It's a missing angular feature.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE

Comment: @GlueLabs at the moment, where I answered that question the MDN documentation page doesn't have this information.